# SphinxQL request similar to LIKE in SQL

Tags: sql, sphinx, sql-like, sphinxql

I was wondered I got the different results of the following requests:

SphinxQL:

```
SELECT ticket_id FROM message WHERE MATCH('*test*') LIMIT 0, 100000 OPTION max_matches = 100000
```

Result was 221 rows

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `ticket_logs` WHERE message LIKE '%test%'
```

Result was 321 rows

What should the SphinxQL request be to get the same result as SQL-request (321 rows).

BTW: The code of Sphinx index is the next:

```
source ticket_logs
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        = 
    sql_db          = test_db
    sql_port        = 3306
    sql_query_pre   = SET NAMES utf8
}

source messages : ticket_logs
{   
    sql_query = \
        SELECT id, ticket_id, message FROM ticket_logs

    sql_field_string = ticket_id
    sql_field_string = message
}

index message
{
    source          = messages
    path            = c:/sphinx/data/index/message
}

searchd
{
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    pid_file        = c:/sphinx/data/searchd.pid
    log             = c:/sphinx/data/log/searchd.log
    query_log       = c:/sphinx/data/log/query.log
    binlog_path     = c:/sphinx/data/binlog/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont appear to have `min_infix_len` defined in your config

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len

... you need it to explicitly enable 'wildcard' queries.

That will give you much closer results.

Comment: Thanks very much) I used min_infix_len = 1 and results became much closer, but still not ideal. I got 315 rows via sphinx and 321 via MySQL. Are any options to make the results more similar?

Comment: And the results of the other request was next: (sphinxQL) select ticket_id from message where match('*Long List*') limit 0, 300000 option max_matches=300000; returned 1369 rows. (SQL) SELECT * FROM `ticket_logs` WHERE message LIKE '%Long List%'; returned 1001 results.

Comment: For the first comment, its probably something like collations, mysql is probably collating the query (eg so e matches é or similar). Sphinx doesnt do that by default. Do some more investigation to find out exactly what rows are different

Comment: For the second, probably the main difference is because sphinx doesnt require the words to be in the same order, or even adjacent!  `LIKE '%Long List%'` is closer to `MATCH('"long list"')` - with quotes to make it **phrase match**. And `match('Long List')` is actully closer to `message LIKE '%long%' AND message LIKE '%list%'`

Comment: Thanks for replies)